# BufferedReader becomes slow after creating it multiple times

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have the following code: what I try to do is to read several times (17.000 times) from `url.openConnection`. I basically want to search and extract the code from a website depending on the word given from an `ArrayList`. However, it becames really slow after creating the `BufferedReader` about 40 times. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++){
        key=(String)words.get(i);
        url=new URL("http://www.tvs.com/x/"+key);
        String word;
        InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(in);
        while((word=reader.readLine())!=null){
            frase=frase+word;
        }
        reader.close();
        in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code is experiencing an O(N^2) slow down due to:

```
frase = frase + word;
```

Each time that executes, it is reallocating memory and copying longer and longer strings into the memory buffer.

It would be better to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++) {
    key = (String)words.get(i);
    url = new URL("http://www.tvs.com/x/" + key);
    try ( InputStream is = url.openStream();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in)) {
        String word;
        while( (word = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(word);
        }
    }
}

frase = sb.toString();
```

Also shown: try-with-resources to ensure the `InputStream`, `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader` are always properly closed, even in case of exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions to use `StringBuffer` are probably what you want, but if you are using Java 8, you could use the [`BufferedReader.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) method and a collector to concatenate the strings you need:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://www.tvs.com/x/" + key);
  try (InputStream is = url.openStream();
       InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in)) {
    String phrase = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
  }
```

Comment: Nice stream solution.  But the OP starts with an `ArrayList` of keys words, so you should map to streams, flatMap to lines, and then collect and join.  :-)

Comment: @AJNeufeld, I think it is going to be more trouble than it is worth to do this in an exception and resource safe way :-(

Answer (score 0):

1. The bottleneck is almost certainly the string contatenation. Use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.
2. And maybe the *sending host* becomes slow. The `BufferedReader` can't read any faster than data is delivered. You may be overloading the server.